# What is Darius III wearing on his head?

Tags: art, clothing, persia, alexander-the-great

In the famous [Alexander Mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Mosaic) found in Pompeii, Darius is wearing some form of head covering, it appears to just be cloth wrapped around his head. What is the hat called? I can't find any information on it. Was this common combat attire, or just artistic?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From this website http://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/clothing-ii , in a section concerning historical clothing it goes into length on several styles of headgear. This style falls under the designation 'tiara'.

> In any event, *the tiara* had a top like a hood, often lined inside with
>   luxurious animal fur. Ordinarily it was worn flat, either pressed down
>   in front to form three knobs or falling in folds on either side. Only
>   *the great king had the right to wear his tiara (kyrbasía) “upright*,”
>   that is, with the top erect, presumably held by inner retainers
>   (Xenophon, Anabasis 2.5.23; Arrian, Anabasis 3.25.3; Plutarch,
>   Artaxerxes 26, 28; idem, Themistocles 29).
>   (emphasis mine)

from the mosaic:

[image: Closeup of Darius]

and a normal 'tiara' from the above mentioned web page shown in 'flat' style:

[image]

Comment: Remarkably similar to the [Papal Tiara](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_tiara), although I don't know if this is mere coincidence.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a [padded coif](https://www.google.com/search?q=padded+coif):

[image: Darius]

[image: padded coif]
<sub>(source: [tripod.com](http://mailmaker.tripod.com/paddedcoif/ccoifa.jpg))</sub>

OT aside: you might also find this [Youtube video from Lindeybeige on mail coifs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbmd-kVgc2E) interesting.

Comment: @user2448131's answer seems better, however, I wouldn't be surprised if the coif were derived from the Persian tiara.